# The definitions of coherent phonons and acoustic phonons

Tags: vibrations, phonons, optical-lattices

I found that the definition of coherent phonon: [A femtosecond laser pulse can initiate collective, in-phase atomic motions in solids called coherent phonons.](https://www.nims.go.jp/ldynamics/Whats_Coherent_Phonon.html)

My question is: what is the difference between coherent phonons and acoustic phonons?
Acoustic phonons also mean the displacement of atoms has the same amplitude, direction and phase. Does it mean atoms move in phase and collectively for acoustic phonons?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Acoustic phonons are the phonons on the lowest branch of the dispersion relation (contrasted with optical phonons). Coherent phonons most likely refer to the [coherent states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_state) of the phonons.